# What's the best Free OS available right now or soon will be?

Tags: operating-systems

My only familiarity is with win7. I'm looking for best new os system. That is light and fast, and can do everything.

I have heard about ubuntu. But don't know if it's the best out there. So i want to know the general community opinion of what's new, best, fast and good looking.

I downloaded chromium os. It was pretty lightweight. But i couldn't figure out how to make it run from hard drive and not usb only.

Comment: lol my rating is 123

Comment: No operating system can do everything.

Comment: ?? I am sorry, im confused by what you're saying. What do you mean by  everything

Comment: Muhammad, you said, "That is light and fast, and can do everything." No operating system can do everything. Linux cannot play (most) Windows games, for example. Windows can't run Linux software.

Comment: If you're talking free, that's pretty much the Linux family.  Fortunately, most Linux distributions, particularly that would be suitable for a newcomer, have a LiveDVD version that you can try out without installing anything.  Try different offerings to see what you like.  One of the key differences that would be the most visible is the desktop.  There are about half a dozen main ones and probably a few dozen in all.  That's the GUI interface and often a collection of utilities.  Most Linux versions are available in a choice of desktops.  Picking a desktop first will make it easier.

Comment: The next most important thing for a newcomer is something that is extremely reliable in terms of everything working the way it is supposed to.  It's hard to learn something new if you constantly run into stuff that doesn't work.  Start out with a major distribution that is based on a stable model and is designed to be newcomer friendly.  Ubuntu is popular but it tends to be a bit buggy relative to the most stable distributions.  Mint is based on Ubuntu but is more refined, and they have Debian-based versions that may be more stable.  OpenSUZE is another good one to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly subjective question, so you'll get fairly subjective answers.

If you are looking for something light I would recommend XUbuntu which is Ubuntu with the Xfce shell. There's also elementaryOS which is a light new distro based on Ubuntu.

I don't really believe there is a 'best' OS either, they all have individual strengths/weaknesses.

Comment: im fine with subjective, because i don't know any os so anything will be an improvement. I'm willing to do my research if i have few things to compare

Comment: That's fine, in that case, you've got my two recommendations above. I'd also have a look at some of the other popular distro's here http://distrowatch.com/

Comment: im liking elementaryOS looks modern..ill give it a try

Comment: I'm writing this comment from ElementaryOS. It Works great for me. But my brother who has two hard drives. Partitions don't show up. After installing Ubunutu there is no dual boot menu. Anyways this was my last question on this site im blocked now.